# What's the input resistance of an opto-isolator?

Tags: power, resistance, load, monitor

I need to sense if a 48 volt power supply is supplying voltage or not, I plan on doing this with a opto-isolator and I am happy with the output circuit from isolator.

Can I connect the input of the isolator between 48 and 0 volts, or do I need to add in a extra resistive load to avoid a shortcircuit style scenario?

Comment: Why do you need an optoisolator? Do you need protection? Do you need to sense absolute yes or no or do you need to know the actual voltage?

Comment: just a yes/no for power on that supply.

Comment: i could use a relay but isolation is prefered in this instance but the same question would exsist would it not i would just be swapping the opto emmitor in the isolator for the coil in the relay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at how much input current your optoisolator needs, and then use a resistor that passes that amount of current when it has 48V across it.

Technically, you should first subtract the voltage drop of the optoisolator from the supply voltage, but in this case, the difference should be negligible.

For example, if your isolator needs 10 mA, you would select a resistor of 4700 Ω, which is the closest standard value to 48V / 0.01A = 4800 Ω. Note that this resistor will be dissipating 48V × 0.01A = 0.48W, so select a 1W resistor for good reliability.

Comment: the isolator has a nominal switching current of 100mA, so by mu reconing if i followed correctly i need a 480 ohm or greater resistor rated at 5.5 watts

Comment: @Wrightyo: The 100mA switching current is probably the amount that the "output" side of the op-amp can handle if given a suitable current on the input.  Typically, an op amp will specify a gain value; if your need the output to switch 15mA and your op amp has a gain of 5, then you'd have to put 3mA through the LED (and should probably put through 5 or so for good measure).  The 100mA value says that the device can only switch that much, even if the gain times the input current would suggest a higher value.

Comment: @Wrightyo: If all you'll be doing is driving a processor input, I'd suggest probably sizing the pull-up resistor so that the op amp has to switch 1mA to pull it all the way to ground, and size the LED resistor so that 1mA will go through the LED.  If you want to ensure that the opto won't turn on with e.g. 20 volts (instead of 48), add a resistor in parallel with the LED.